# How to fix to get specific data in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP. I try to build simple page with PHP and MySql, but failed to display the spesific data.

I try this: [Get data from MySQL database by specific id in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777802/get-data-from-mysql-database-by-specific-id-in-url) to display data by "id_pemesanan" not "id" from the database.

But it's failed.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id_pemesanan'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mad");
$query = "SELECT * FROM pesanan WHERE id_pemesanan ='". $id."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
{
echo "<p>$row[asal]</p>";
    }
?>
```

This is my database table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `pesanan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_pemesanan` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pemesan` text NOT NULL,
  `asal` text NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `tujuan` text NOT NULL,
  `lat_tujuan` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `long_tujuan` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `jarak` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

I want display the spesific data using url like: http://localhost/mios/open/lengkap.php?=11772

The "11772" in the url is from "id_pemesanan"

I want the code to display the data. But, the error messages come.

Here the error massage:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id_pemesanan in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mios\open\lengkap.php on line 2
```

Comment: You are missing to pass your get parameter on url . See i have answer on this

Comment: Have a look at ["SQL Injection"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: This is more of a typo question. VTC as typo

Answer (score 2):

Your url must be like following..

```
http://localhost/mios/open/lengkap.php?id_pemesanan=11772
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to pass your get parameter on url

```
http://localhost/mios/open/lengkap.php?id_pemesanan=11772
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your request URL is missing parameter `id_pemesanan`, should like this:

```
http://localhost/mios/open/lengkap.php?id_pemesanan=11772
```

See [Query string - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

> Typical URL containing a query string is as follows:
>
> http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret
>
> When a server receives a request for such a page, it may run a program, passing the query string, which in this case is, `name=ferret` unchanged, to the program. The question mark is used as a separator, and is not part of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be add query parameter in url, because that error is about index to GET not found query parameter with index id_pemesanan.

```
http://localhost/mios/open/lengkap.php?id_pemesanan=11772
```