# php - display ID in URL

Tags: php

for the past few i have been trying to get the ID of the event a user registers to inside the URL in order to show all details in that event.

Ive tried [Get data from MySQL database by specific id in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777802/get-data-from-mysql-database-by-specific-id-in-url/32778358)
But it doesnt seem to work for what i am trying to do.
Or i am doing it wrong, i got more progress with this code

```
     <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $QUERY3 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM `registration` WHERE `user_id`='$userid'");
    $GETEVENTZ = mysqli_fetch_array($QUERY3);
}
?>
    <?php 
    $eventid = $GETEVENTZ['event_id']; 
    echo '<li> <a href="leaderboard.php?eventid='.$eventid.'"><i class="icon icon-list"></i><span>Leaderboards</span></a> </li>'
?>
```

Just to try and get the ID in but im getting a normal page 
with the url being

```
leaderboard.php?eventid=
```

and no ID after, no errors are popping up, page and everything loads, just doesnt add ID. cant seem to find the issue

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($eventid)` or `print_r($eventid)`? Somehow I get the impression that `$eventid` is not a string that can be echoed.

Comment: `$var_dump($GETEVENTZ);` Ensure query does not fail. Use prepared statements even if you believe your injected data is safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using: `$GETEVENTZ = mysqli_fetch_array($QUERY3);`

Your code is expecting an array return. So you cannot just simply use:
`$eventid = $GETEVENTZ['event_id'];`

A quick fix can be `$eventid = $GETEVENTZ[0]['event_id']` if you are expecting a single row return from your query.

But the proper way to handle this is to use `mysqli_fetch_row()` instead.

You can also dump the result set first to debug what your query is returning.

Comment: what i am trying to do is show content on a page based off event ID, because each ID has different data, but i cant seem to get the ID in the URL with any of these codes

Comment: Yup, I get that you want to display different data based on event_id. But can you dump $GETEVENTZ? What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The session super global is not the one to use. Use $_GET to get information from the URL.

```
<?php
if(isset($GET['user_id'])){
    $userid = $GET['user_id'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM `registration` WHERE `user_id`=?";

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query3)) {
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $userid);

      $stmt->execut();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
    }

}
?>



<?php 

// this section does not demonstrate getting the value from $result
// I will update answer later, must research mysqli more. 
     echo '<li> <a href="leaderboard.php?eventid='.$eventid.'"><i class="icon icon-list"></i><span>Leaderboards</span></a> </li>'
?>
```

Disclaimer: I don't use mysqli, so my answer is a best guess on that portion.  Be sure to research how to properly use prepared statements at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: This still seems to give me a blank url and for user_id you put ? what am i supposed to exactly put there, (still new to php) wouldnt that be the $_SESSION['user_id']

Comment: The question mark is a placeholder for a prepared statement. Then you bind a value to it and execute the statement. You should never, ever use untrusted user input directly in a query. As for session variable, this would be something that you had set in a previous page. I don’t see any evidence that you have done this. As for the value of event_id, I misread your code—too sleepy. That requires getting a value from the database and mysqli has such an odd interface that I would have to take a lot of time to figure out its idiosyncrasies

Comment: What you need to do is break this problem into single issues. Your first issue is just accessing the user_id. Once you demonstrate to yourself that you have captured user_id, then you can tackle getting a result from the database. After that, figure out how to display the info.   Your question is about step 3 but you must first solve the 2 steps before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hopefully it will work.

```
<?php
$DB = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
/* check connection */
if ($DB->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $DB->connect_error);
    exit();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $QUERY3 = "SELECT * FROM registration  WHERE user_id='$userid'";
    $result = $DB->query($QUERY3);
    $GETEVENTZ = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $eventid = $GETEVENTZ['event_id']; 
    printf ("%s", $eventid);
}
echo '<li> <a href="leaderboard.php?eventid='.$eventid.'"><i class="icon icon-list"></i><span>Leaderboards</span></a> </li>';
?>
```

Comment: i am still getting nothing in return in the Url, still leaderboard.php?evenid=

Comment: Did Printf function print your $eventid Or still it's returning an empty value

Comment: Makdia, still returning an empty value

Comment: Can you please check your $_SESSION variable is working perfectly? I think your $userid didn't get any value. So please check your $userid.

Answer (score 0):

Answer -

Session id was labeled (userid) instead of (user_id)

then after i stated if user session has user ID then print the event ID and then show page, which then it redirects me to the correct page with ID of event

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $GETUSRID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $GETRANKD = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM `registrations` WHERE `user_id`='$GETUSRID'");
        $GETRD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GETRANKD);



 $eventid = $GETRD['event_id']; 
    printf ("%s", $eventid);
}
echo '<li> <a href="leaderboard.php?eventid='.$eventid.'"><i class="icon icon-list"></i><span>Leaderboards</span></a> </li>';
```